# Simple search form doesn't return any results

Tags: php, mysql

I have this simple search form but doesn't return anything. When I try `var_dump($ser)` is show `null`. Any idea why is this?

```
include 'include/db.php';

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT caption,name FROM images WHERE caption LIKE '%$_GET[caption]%' LIMIT 0,1");

$caption = $sql['caption'];
$name = $sql['name'];

while($ser = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

$out .= "<div id=\"picture\">";
$out .= "<img style=\"width:100%;margin:0 auto;\" src=\"/upload/".$ser['name']."\" /><br />";
$out .= "<div id=\"caption\">";
$out .= "<h1>" . $ser['caption'] . "</h1>";
$out .= "</div><br />";
}
```

And here is the form

```
    <form action="../search.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="caption" size="15">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Is pretty basic but still hard to understand what is wrong.

Comment: `$_GET[caption]`. There is no index that has a predefined constant value of caption, you need to encapsulate this with `'caption'`.

Comment: And add a `or die(mysqli_error());` to the end of your `$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT caption,name FROM images WHERE caption LIKE '%$_GET[caption]%' LIMIT 0,1") *ADD HERE*`. Thus, mySQL is going to tell you what error occurred.

Comment: but when I make it `'%$_GET['caption']%'` I get error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)`

Comment: try replace fragment of code to: `WHERE caption LIKE '%{$_GET['caption']}%' LIMIT 0,1` . And you have vulnerability here

Comment: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array`

Comment: Is there any good tutorial for search engine on my site where I can read and learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
$result= mysqli_query($conn, "select caption,name from images where caption like '%'") or die (mysqli_error());

while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $line['caption'].$line['name']."<br/>";
}
```

Check if you have an error or some results

Comment: Error `Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given`

Comment: Check your connection. Must be mysqli_connect and not mysql_connect. This message means your parameter aren't a correct resource. Maybe it can empty. Check also your connection

Comment: Yes, it was my connection but now is this `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array`

Comment: This message means, you aren't used correct the mysqli resource. Please send the complete code from php.

Answer (score 0):

```
$caption = $_GET['caption'];

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT caption,name FROM images WHERE caption LIKE '%'".$caption."'%' LIMIT 0,1");

while($ser = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

   echo $ser['name']." ".$ser['caption'];
}
```